# Write enabled files in shared folder opened as readonly in some applications

Tags: mount, nautilus, read-only, fuse, eog

From Nautilus using the `Connect to Server` option I have setup a shared folder in my Ubuntu desktop that points to a Samba shared folder in my NAS. The user that connects to the shared folder has read and write permissions in all files and folders, and I can perfectly read, rename o create files in the shared folder directly from Nautilus.

But if I open a file from the share with some applications I cannot make any changes to it because it is opened as readonly. For example, this is happening to me when opening a image with eog (default image viewer) or a .kdbx file with KeepassX. However, if I open a text file with gedit or a LibreOffice document, these applications treat the remote files as writable.

I have checked that the shared folder is mounted as writable:

> gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)

I have also tried mounting the shared folder using cifs from /etc/fstab with no luck.

I have discarded that this problem could have something to do with server configuration or user permissions as I can write in the share with no problem through Nautilus, LibreOffice or gedit. But I seems strange to me that applications like eog see all remote files as readonly. Maybe I need to change some configuration in the mounted share in my desktop computer for these applications? Someone has experienced this same problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you do `ls -l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally been able to access with write permission to all files from every application mounting the shared folder in */etc/fstab*.

The trick has been to use *uid* and *gid* along with *forceuid* and *forcegid* in the mount options of */etc/fstab* to map a local user with write permissions when dealing with files and folders of the mounted samba share.

It won´t be for sure the best practice for use when mounting remote shares, but at least it is working for me. What I still don´t know is how to use these mount options when mounting the shared folder using Nautilus.